# Mysql unknow column exception

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am getting unknown column exception from this query

```
SELECT sessions.*, sessions.id AS session_id FROM sessions WHERE session_id = 1;
```

It says "unknown column session_id"

But I have mentioned "session_id" is an alias of "sessions.id".

I can not change the where condition. I can only change the select part. because the actual query is too complex and I don't want to mess up this query.

I am using mysql 5.7

Comment: It seems a little unnecessary selecting the `session_id` if you already know the `session_id` as you are using it in the `where` clause

Comment: You can **not** use aliases in your `where` clause. They may not be evaluated then.

Comment: So try `sessions.id = 1`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have already mentioned that I can not change the where part. I want to know If I can make this query working by modifying only the select part.

Comment: I think that @juergend has already made it obvious you cannot have an alias in a where clause. So you are going to have to take a deep breath and change the where clause

Comment: *"I can not change the where condition."* - Well, your other option is to re-name the column in the table schema itself.  I suspect changing the `WHERE` clause sounds a bit more reasonable overall though.

Comment: Or use the "hacky" SQL statement `SELECT sessions.*, sessions.id AS session_id FROM sessions HAVING session_id = 1;` ...  i find it wierd to use it because HAVING should be used in combination with GROUP BY..  In this case the HAVING works just like the WHERE does.

Comment: I suppose another option would be to wrap the whole `SELECT` in a sub-query without a `WHERE` clause and then apply the `WHERE` clause around it.  Something like: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT sessions.*, sessions.id AS session_id FROM sessions) WHERE session_id = 1`  I doubt that would perform as well.  And, more to the point, if your overall goal is to prevent an already complex query from becoming *more* complex and *more* difficult to support... hacky solutions are not the way to go.

Comment: @David It didn't work also. thanks for this creative Idea.

Comment: "hacky solutions are not the way to go." true @David your option is better i didn't call mine hackly without a reason.. Besides it might not be totally hacky by the way.. SQL1992 defines " A grouped table is a set of groups derived during the evaluation of a <group by clause> or a <having clause>. A group is a multiset of rows in which all values of the grouping column or columns are equal if a <group by clause> is specified, **or the group is the entire table if no <group by clause> is specified.**

Comment: ... @David with other words `SELECT sessions.*, sessions.id AS session_id FROM sessions HAVING session_id = 1;` is perfect valid ANSI SQL1992.. i don't own documents of other SQL standards by the way so i don't know if they changed the standard about this feature...

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I think either way the OP is looking at the problem from the wrong perspective.  If the core of the problem is that they have one big query that’s difficult to understand and support, then that’s the first problem to be addressed.  First make the code supportable, then add new features to it.  By looking for other ways to wedge a new feature into already unknown code they’re just digging the hole deeper.

Comment: Topicstarter @David 's query didn't work because it's missing the alias for the subqeury. it should have been more like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT sessions.*, sessions.id AS session_id FROM sessions) AS alias WHERE session_id = 1`

Comment: "I think either way the OP is looking at the problem from the wrong perspective. If the core of the problem is that they have one big query that’s difficult to understand and support, then that’s the first problem to be addressed." indeed @David the topicstarter should read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the final touch. Its working after modifying query to `SELECT * FROM (SELECT sessions.*, sessions.id AS session_id FROM sessions) AS alias WHERE session_id = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it to work by following the suggestions from @David and @RaymondNijland. So now my query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT sessions.*, sessions.id AS session_id 
    FROM sessions
) AS alias
WHERE session_id = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think that its gonna be slower than my previous query. I mean there must be some kind of optimizations (short circuiting) done by MySQL before executing this query. anyway thanks for your suggestion, I will test both queries.

Comment: @Jim Wright I have tested it in phpMyAdmin. There was no issues regarding speed using above query. can you suggest a method to test and compare these queries ? I want to be more confident for this solution

Comment: You won't see a noticeable difference until you have more rows. But to grasp the concept of why this would be slower, take the following example. Imagine you went into a library and you had to find books starting with "The". By this method you would have to go through each book attaching a label of the name on each book. After that, you would have to look through each book (again!) searching for books that start with "The". This means that you have to go over the entire collection of books twice. Would it not be better to only look at the books once and be more specific?

Comment: @JimWright I've tested it with a table having around 50000 records and both queries took same amount of time to execute.

Answer (score 3):

Aliases are not accessible in the `WHERE` statement. You need to use the actual column name as follows:

```
SELECT sessions.*, sessions.id AS session_id FROM sessions WHERE sessions.id = 1;
```